# How to do I implement oop with a number of questions

Tags: c++, oop

I have about 40 questions. (all the answers to the questions are of either int or float data type)
I will display the question and ask the user to input his/her answer.
Then I will check if the answer is correct or not.

### I need to implement this program in object oriented programming.

I thought about doing it this way,questions by questions..but is there another way of doing this? Please help me..
The code below is sort of a pseudocode . I use c++ .

```
class workout{
private:
 float variables...;
public:
 workout();
 workout(float variables...);
 void answers();
 int Display();
 ~workout();
};
...
void workout::answers(){
 declare variables;
 display question1;
 input answer1
 check if correct
 display question2;
 input answer2
 check if correct
 display question3;
 ..and so on..
}
workout::~workout(){
}
int main(){
...
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well you could have a Question class, and then go from there. Here's an example.

```cpp
class Question
{
public:
    std::string question
    float answer;

    Question(std::string _question, float _answer)
        : question(_question), answer(_answer) {}

    void Display() {}
    bool Check(float input) {}
};
```

And then maybe create an array of questions?